# How to convert blob to an image and store it into a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

**here blob is an object which consits of type image and how should I convert this object into an image and store it into a folder**

```
 //response = file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fmlfinal-1dd02798-2aa3-441f-95ea-d0aad1366fbd/Camera/1f29269c-64c9-4bb3-b3bf-25db0b88896a.jpg
            const blob = await response.blob()
            const body = new FormData()
            body.append('file', blob)
            const responseserver = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/upload', {
            body
            })
```

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50537735/convert-blob-to-image-file/50538148 help?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by creating an ArrayBuffer from the blob and then writing the buffer to a file.