# Convert Outlook .msg file blob to .png

Tags: javascript, vue.js, blob, msg

I have a `msg` file in the form of a blob and I need to display it as a `png` (or really any other image format) in my Vue project.

I've found an API that will do it ([ConvertAPI](https://www.convertapi.com/)), but they would store and process the `msg` file on their servers, and it also costs money, so I'm looking for more secure and simpler alternatives.

Is there a way to do this conversion locally in a fairly straightforward manner?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468643/how-to-display-mysql-blob-image-in-html-using-vuejs

Comment: found this question that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50537735/convert-blob-to-image-file/50538148

Comment: I think that answer would work if the blob were representing an image to begin with, but the blob I'm starting with represents an Outlook `msg` file. Doesn't it need to be converted to an image somehow first?